# onEndReached function calls at first, before user reach to end of flat list

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I want to execute a function, when user reached to end of `flatList` but the function is running up just on component loading before every thing:

```
loadMore() {

alert('YouGot to end');

}


 render() {
    return (
    <FlatList

    data={this.state.foods}
    extraData={[this.state, this.props]}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
    onEndReached={this.loadMore()}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0}
  />

  );
 }
```

load more alert is showing up at first moment will  when component inits at first!! and even it doesn't show again when i scroll to end of `flatlist`

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you render the `FlatList` before your data is loaded.

You should check if the data is loaded and then render the List. If not it will trigger the `onEndReached` method because the initial list render is empty.

Comment: i bound this.state.foods staticly.. but in another component i checked loading data an the whole component will render after state data is loaded. and still have same problem :(

Comment: @ImanSalehi then also pass isLoading to this component or implement shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: which component do you mean FlatList component or the current one which i render flat list in it ? actually it will be great if you show me an example about